# How can I  print multiple pages on a single page via my iPhone?

Tags: ios, printing

Is it possible print multiple pages of a Word, PowerPoint or PDF document on a single page natively from iPhone 4S?

Otherwise, are there other apps out there that allows me to do so?

What I mean by printing multiple pages of a document on a single page is something what we have on the usual Mac OS and Windows OS, where there is often a "handout" option to print multiple slides or pages of a document onto a single physical paper page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not aware of any apps that can do that. You certainly can't print handouts with the native printing menu.

You could create the handout document on a computer and then click the "Save as PDF" option in the print dialogue. Then you could transfer the PDF handout file to your iPhone, which you could then print from there.

Answer (score 2):

Not natively, but you can with [Printopia](http://www.ecamm.com/mac/printopia/) running on a Mac connected to your printer.

To do this, you need to first create a *very* simple Automator action. Open up Automator, and create a Print Plugin. For the Workflow, you only need to add the "Run Shell Script" action. Make sure the action is set to "Pass input: as arguments". The shell script needs only a single line:

```
lp -o number-up=4 -o media=Letter "$*"
```

The specifics of the line might depend on your needs. In this case, I'm printing to my default printer (so is't not specified). I found that without the "media" option the result was was not scaled properly. You can define `number-up` as either 1, 2, 4, or 16.

If you want to specify a specific printer, use the following instead:

```
lp -d <printer> -o number-up=4 -o media=Letter "$*"
```

where `<printer>` is one of your print queues. You can find these by executing `lpstat -a` at a terminal prompt.

That's it. Now save the action. I saved mine as "4-Up Print".

Next open Printopia in the System Preferences. Click the `+` to add a new destination, select "Add PDF Workflow", and pick the Automator Workflow that you created in the previous step.

When printing from your iOS device, pick the newly created Printopia Air Print destination. Obviously you need to be on the same local network as the Mac.

Enjoy!

Comment: It also works with Printopia 3.0
I exported the workflow to iCloud and first added it with a normal print-command in any Program to the pdf-menu. Afterward I could add the workflow with the "+" in Printopia (Add PDF Workflow)

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you could set up Mail rules on a Mac linked to a complex AppleScript script that could get you your desired results. But honestly, its too much if you ask me.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Printopia](http://ecamm.com/mac/printopia/). Not sure if it will do what you are looking to do from your iOS device but worth trying. Might want to contact the Printopia developer to see if they offer that capability before purchasing the app for the App Store.

Comment: I have Printopia and love it. Although you can customize many of the destination printer's settings, "Copies and Layout" is not (currently) one of them.

Answer (score 0):

The app Printer Pro by Readdle will do it, it is the cheapest app that I see that can do it. It took me awhile to find it but so far it works great

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  We're trying to find the best answers and those answers will be more than just one line.  Providing supporting info and links can also help the OP, and others, find additional info for themselves.  See [answer] on how to provide a quality answer. - From Review

Answer (score 0):

I use WPS app.. it's great and you can print multiple pages on one sheet.. Open the file using this app, then from ..file option.. choose print ..

Comment: Is this app [WPS Office](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/wps-office/id1491101673) for iOS?